# Latex includepdf how to pass offset from command

Tags: latex

my goal is not to hardcode the offset in the includepdf command

so instead of

```
\newcommand{\myscale}{0.90}
\includepdf[scale=\myscale,offset=0mm -5mm,angle=90,pagecommand=\subsection{my title}]{file.pdf}
```

it would be great to write something like this

```
\newcommand{\myscale}{0.90}
\newcommand{\offset}{0mm -5mm}
\includepdf[scale=\myscale,offset=\offset,angle=90,pagecommand=\subsection{my title}]{file.pdf}
```

in fact, it is working for the numerical scale value but not for the offset string.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use two separate macros, e.g.  `offset=\xoffset{} \yoffset`

Comment: brilliant solution. i did try `offset=\xoffset \yoffset` which is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you use two separate macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\myscale}{0.90}
\newcommand{\xoffset}{0mm}
\newcommand{\yoffset}{-5mm}
\includepdf[scale=\myscale,offset=\xoffset{} \yoffset,angle=90,pagecommand=\subsection{my title}]{example-image-duck}


\end{document}
```